# Apache mod_proxy_http2 as forward proxy

Tags: apache, http, http2, http-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to configure apache as a `HTTP/2` *forward proxy* using `mod_proxy_http2` to translate requests from `HTTP/1.1` to `HTTP/2` protocol.

Something like this:

**[Client]** ---(HTTP/1.1)---> **[Proxy]** ---(HTTP/2)---> **[Server]**

The module's [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html) does not mention anything about setting it up as a *forward proxy*.

Is this kind of configuration possible? Any clues? Alternatives?

Comment: What’s the reason behind such setup?

Comment: @emix I have a legacy client HTTP/1.1 application that needs to access a server that supports HTTP/2 **only**.